# Horrible grafical error, unusable

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, drivers, laptop

Hi I am brand new to Linux and Ubuntu and I recently attempted to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a really old laptop I found in my basement, a Presario 2700T. THe installation went well but then it went to the log in screen and it's just a jumbled mess of colors. I thought 'oh maybe it's just 12.10.' So i downloaded 12.04 and the same thing, albeit slightly better. I think it has something to with drivers but I have no clue how to install drives when I cant use the computer.

Comment: While this isn't your *exact* problem, but this question should help: http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/44179

Answer (score 0):

im going to assume the card is a ATI Mobility Radeon M6 ; based on what i've read on the particular model

you're going to need to install the proper drivers, not only to get ubuntu running properly but to also allow for 3d acceleration

the following link may or may not help :v

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=246746